# mount shared file system in function fails

Tags: bash, function, mount

I have a bash script where I do a function call.
In the called function I want to mount a shared file system

in main (I know bash does not have a "main)

```
mount_file_system

function mount_file_system () {
    mount -t nfs <ip>:/remote_path/shared /local_path/shared
}
```

When I execute the script I get the error:
    segmentation fault

When I change the function to:

```
function mount_file_system () {
    MOUNTING=`mount -t nfs <ip>:/remote_path/shared /local_path/shared`
}
```

I get the error:
fork: Cannot allocate memory

The system runs out of memory

```
free -m
```

but I don't know why the mount process would chew up all the memory.

I can run the mount command on the command line and all works as expected.

What is different when calling it within a function. I assume quite a bit, but I don't understand why. Yes I understand that a function call does behave differently than just run the command at the command line

Cheers,
Roland

Comment: What is <ip> in that script? Is that literal?

Comment: Can you mount the NFS folder outside of the script?

Comment: Hi @geckos, <ip> is just a placeholder for the real IP address. And yes, when I ran the mount command on the command line it mounts the shared file system no problem

Comment: I would check (1) SELinux, (2) /etc/security/limits.conf, (3) dmesg (during the mound)

Comment: Thank you @geckos, I will do that. As a side not, I was also able to run the mount command within a bash script, and it mounted the shared file system successfully. Just when I execute the mount command in a bash function do I see this weird behavior of the mount process to get stuck and run out of memory

Comment: You can make the testing faster by `a() { mount -t nfs ...; }; a` this would be the same that executing in the script as a function. Are you on ubuntu? Can't this be a dash vs bash problem? Is really weird that executing something inside a function leads to segmentation fault. IMHO the problem is out of our sight, is the same PATH?

Comment: Update, while at work I tried the mount command again within a function call and it was successful. Not really sure why it failed from home.

Comment: and thank you @geckos for all your help and info